# RでCSVデータの文字を置換したい

Tags: r

R初心者です。
R言語でCSV（エクセル）データのある項目の固定した文字を置換したい。
例えばA列の「？」という文字を「あ」に置換したい。
このような場合のスクリプトを教えてほしいです。

大変ざっくりした質問で恐縮ですが、ご協力お願いします。

Comment: ネット上には情報があふれています. こちらを参考にした上でわからないことを再度質問してください https://stats.biopapyrus.jp/r/basic/string.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stringr`パッケージの`str_replace`が良いかと思います。
以下に、`iris`データを使った例を記載してありますので、ご参照下さい

```
# irisデータ Species列の'g'を'G'に変換する
# 変換前確認
iris %>% distinct(Species)

# 変換
iris.mod <- iris %>% mutate(Species = stringr::str_replace(Species, 'g', 'G'))

# 変換後確認
iris.mod %>% distinct(Species)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。おかげさまで解決しました！